# Вираз для позначення надмірного вживання щойно надбаного вміння

Tags: вибір-слова

Чи існує прислів'я чи слово для позначення надмірного використання чогось нещодавно вивченого? Наприклад, раніше ти все робив за допомогою цвяхів і все було добре, а тут ти навчився користуватись викруткою і гвинтами і відтепер тільки ними й користуєшся повністю забувши цвяхи.

Comment: (1) «*[Co za dużo, to niezdrowo](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/co_za_du%C5%BCo,_to_niezdrowo)*». (2) [Law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument): «*I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail.*» — Abraham Maslow

Comment: Є відоме: _І чужому научайтесь, й свого не цурайтесь_. Доволі схоже, якщо не знати весь контекст, хех.

Comment: Навчи дурня Богу молитись - він і лоба розіб'є.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перефразовуючи Арахама Маслоу і Абрахама Каплана:

> Знайшов молоток, тепер все видається цвяхами.

- У Маслоу звучить так:

> Я вважаю, що якщо єдиний ваш інструмент - це молоток, то спокусливо вважати все цвяхами.

- У Каплана так:

> Я називаю це законом інструмента і його можна сформулювати так: Дайте маленькому хлопчику молоток і він буде думати, що все навколо потребує стукання.

---

[Тут](https://uk.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%27%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8:_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) вже не зовсім про надмірне, але майже в тему:

> В умілого і долото рибу ловить!

Answer (score 2):

Можна підійти з іншого боку: **Повторення мати навчання.**

> З латинського: Repetiljo est inaier studiorum.
>
> Старовинне латинське прислів'я.
>
> Є інша, менш відома версія (можливо, це просто початковий вигляд
>   загальновідомого прислів'я): Повторення мати навчання, але і притулок
>   для ледарів.
>
> Використовується як форма заохочення старанних занять.

А також вислів Горація: **Двічі повторене сподобається**.

- [Латинські вирази](https://uk.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8)